# How to add base/baseHref to Nx/Vite manifest.json file

Tags: vite, nxjs

How can I prefix the file, css, and assets in a Vite manifest.json file with a CDN URL?

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: 'https://my-cdn.com/',
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: '/path/to/main.js'
    }
  }
})
```

but the end result is:

```
{
  "main.js": {
    "file": "assets/main.4889e940.js",
    "src": "main.js",
    "isEntry": true,
    "dynamicImports": [],
    "css": ["assets/main.b82dbe22.css"],
    "assets": ["assets/asset.0ab0f9cd.png"]
  }
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  "main.js": {
    "file": "https://my-cdn.com/assets/main.4889e940.js",
    "src": "main.js",
    "isEntry": true,
    "dynamicImports": [],
    "css": ["https://my-cdn.com/assets/main.b82dbe22.css"],
    "assets": ["https://my-cdn.com/assets/asset.0ab0f9cd.png"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Seeing the code, in concrete [manifest.ts](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/manifest.ts) and [ssrManifestPlugin.ts](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/src/node/ssr/ssrManifestPlugin.ts) only the ssrManifest option look for the `base` option to generate the URL's with the CDN string.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you need to add a base property with the URL or path in the project.json file under targets/build/options.

Here is an example project.json config file:

```json
{
    "name": "app",
    "$schema": "node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
    "sourceRoot": "./src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "targets": {
        "build": {
            "executor": "@nrwl/vite:build",
            "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
            "defaultConfiguration": "production",
            "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/app",
                "base": "https://my-cdn.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you are using vite without NX, then you can provide a base argument to the vite build command.

An example:

```bash
vite build --base="https://my-cdn.com"
```